# Why does the VC2012 compiler get into a stackoverflow (error C1063)?

Tags: visual-c++, stl, compiler-errors, iterator, stack-overflow

I had my own working iterator to go over pixels in an image horizontally or vertically. Via template parameter, it could be `const` or not (neat trick from [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-defining-iterato/184401331)).

Then I realized there is a [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) base class and I thought I'd make my stuff more *STLly* and inherit from it.

Unfortunately, now **Visual Studio 2012** (Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2) won't compile it anymore. I actually managed to get the compiler stackoverflow. This is the message:

> Error 1   error C1063: compiler limit : compiler stack overflow   d:\…\source.cpp 42  1   ConsoleApplication3

A very stripped down version of my class looks like this:

```
#include <iterator>

// This comes from the outer image class.
typedef float color_type;

template<bool IS_CONST = false>
struct Iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, color_type>
{
    // This is myself...
    typedef Iterator<IS_CONST> iterator;
    // ... and my variants.
    typedef Iterator<true> const_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;

    // Make base class typedefs available.
    typedef typename iterator::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename iterator::difference_type difference_type;

    // My own typedefs to deal with immutability.
    typedef value_type const & const_reference;
    typedef typename std::conditional<IS_CONST, const_reference, typename iterator::reference>::type reference;

    Iterator()
        : _position(nullptr),
        _step()
    {
    }

    Iterator(value_type * const position, difference_type const step)
        : _position(position),
        _step(step)
    {
    }

    iterator const operator-(difference_type n) const
    {
        return iterator(*this) -= n;
    }

    difference_type operator-(iterator const rhs) const
    {
        assert(_step == rhs._step);
        return (_position - rhs._position) / _step;
    }

protected:
    value_type * _position;
    difference_type _step;
};

int main()
{
    float a = 3.141f;
    // Instanciate all variants.
    Iterator<false> empty;
    Iterator<true> const_empty;
    Iterator<false> some(&a, 5);
    Iterator<true> const_some(&a, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Removing either one of the two `operator-` makes the compiler happy.

Can somebody emplain to me what the problem is here? Or even better provide a fix for it?

Thanks

---

**Update:** Oh and by the way, [GCC 4.7.2 happily compiles it](http://ideone.com/RflAiS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my, that was dumb… Playing with [jerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16700465/581002) led me to find my mistake. Of course the compiler gets into recursion thus leading to a stackoverflow. When I wrote

```
// Make base class typedefs available.
typedef typename iterator::value_type value_type;
typedef typename iterator::difference_type difference_type;
```

my intention was to make the base class' `typedef`s easily available. But writing `iterator` without any qualification refers to the class itself, thanks to my other `typedef` above, **duh!**

```
// This is myself...
typedef Iterator<IS_CONST> iterator;
```

So by correctly referring to the `iterator` in `std`, the problem is solved *and* I get to keep my `typedef`s.

```
// Make base class typedefs available.
typedef std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, color_type> base_class;
typedef typename base_class::value_type value_type;
typedef typename base_class::difference_type difference_type;
```

Interesting though, that GCC doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I may not have made the self-referential problem entirely clear. In your (non-simplified) code, does the iterator actually depend on the template parameter? If not, the `typedef`s should not be necessary as they're inherited from the base class already. I tried to demonstrate this in the solution code (http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/1pg and http://ideone.com/mEX18H) by using them in main.

Comment: By the way, MSVC++ is notoriously bad at correctly doing two-phase lookup for templates. Clearly, `difference_type` is a dependent name, but VC++ is still trying to look it up before the template is instantiated. It only seems to happen when there is a function or operator override that takes the type as a paramater.

Comment: In deed the `typedef`s are not necessary at in this example.

Comment: Not needing them makes the whole problem disappear and the question unasked. But for the full code the types have to be qualified, so luckily I don't have to revert asking it. Phew.

Comment: Even if just removing the typedefs solved the problem in your full code, it's still an interesting question (and probably will be useful to future readers). There would be no need to delete it : ). So I take it in your original code, the base class does depend on the template parameter? If so, I'd recommend editing the question to note that difference between the two pieces of code (but please leave the current code as is).

Comment: No no, sorry, I forgot the `<irony>` tags. I wouldn't undo anything. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Minimal example:

```
template<bool B>
struct Iterator
{
    typedef typename Iterator<B>::some_type some_type ;

    int foo();

    int foo(some_type n);
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Output from http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/2eQ:

```
testvc.cpp(1) : info : Could not find CompilerVersion hint, using default compiler version 'VS2012CTP'
testvc.cpp(1) : info : Ignoring directive '#include', which cannot be used in this online version of the Visual C++ compiler
testvc.cpp(1) : info : Automatically importing the Standard Library headers which match this online version of the Visual C++ compiler
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.51025 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

testvc.cpp
--\testvc.cpp(10) : fatal error C1063: compiler limit : compiler stack overflow
        --\testvc.cpp(11) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Iterator' being compiled
Internal Compiler Error in .  You will be prompted to send an error report to Microsoft later.
```

To solve it, remove the following lines from your code:

```
// Make base class typedefs available.
typedef typename iterator::value_type value_type;
typedef typename iterator::difference_type difference_type;
```

It then compiles in Visual C++ (http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/1pg):

```
testvc.cpp(1) : info : Could not find CompilerVersion hint, using default compiler version 'VS2012CTP'
testvc.cpp(1) : info : Ignoring directive '#include', which cannot be used in this online version of the Visual C++ compiler
testvc.cpp(1) : info : Automatically importing the Standard Library headers which match this online version of the Visual C++ compiler
testvc.cpp(2) : info : Ignoring directive '#include', which cannot be used in this online version of the Visual C++ compiler
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.51025 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

testvc.cpp
testvc.cpp(64) : info : File compiled with no errors!
```

and works as expected in GCC (http://ideone.com/mEX18H):

```
result: Success     time: 0s    memory: 2896 kB     returned value: 0 
input: no

output:
0 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much—and sorry. I'd like to give you more points, but it wasn't quite the answer, yet.